# which is better to use a view or a materialised view?

Tags: oracle, view, plsql, oracle10g, materialized-views

So I have a process to design where there are few base tables on which I have to create a view and from that view I will extract and derive data and insert into an another table.
we would use this last table for extracting reports

This process will run daily, since the data on the base tables have updates have everyday.
he whole purpose of this process is to make things "faster" for reporting,

So my concern here is with using the view. I am wondering if a materialized view would be better to use here in terms of performance instead the view or view itself would be the better.

Has anyone had to deal with such situation and found an approach that performs well and works efficiently??

Any leads on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: A view on its own won't make anything faster, it's just hiding the underlying queries. When you query the view you're still hitting the base tables. A materialized view is a snapshot of the data. If you're querying a significant chunk of the same data multiple times then a materialized view might be more performant. There isn't necessarily a simple answer about which will be better for you, at least with the information provided. Why not benchmark both?

Comment: Querying a view will use the underlying table indexes. You can [check the execution plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/ex_plan.htm) to see what it's doing.

Comment: @AlexPoole is spot on. You won't know (and we can't tell you) on your machine with your data in your structure until you go ahead and benchmark both examples. Read up on the optimizer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/optimops.htm) and best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response. Just one question this please, While selecting data from the view , would it use the base table indexes.?

Comment: @Nitin_Sen, read Alex's comment. It's just two comments above.